# Solving ${d^2 x \over dt^2}=-\omega^2x +\alpha x^2,$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

On solving a Lagrangian, I obtained the Lagrangian equation of motion as
$${d^2 x \over dt^2}=-\omega^2x +\alpha x^2,$$  Where $\omega$ and $\alpha$ are constants and t is the time.
Could anyone please help me to find an analytic solution to this differential equation?

My attempt

Multiplying both sides with $\dot x$, we get
$$\dot x {d\dot x\over dt}=(\alpha x^2-\omega^2 x){dx\over dt}$$
gives

$${1\over2} {d(\dot x)^2\over dt}=(\alpha x^2-\omega^2 x){dx\over dt}$$
gives

$${1\over2} d(\dot x)^2=(\alpha x^2-\omega^2 x)dx$$
gives

$$(\dot x)^2={2\over 3}\alpha x^3-\omega^2x^2$$

Could anyone please assist me to move further

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a non linaer ode , I think analytic solution ente chance less annu

Comment: It can be integated by multiplication with $\dot x$. Next you'll get a first order ODE which can be integrated in terms of elliptic functions

Comment: Please see the edits in "my attempt", could you please assist me to move further, I don't have a good idea about elliptic functions and their applications in differential equations.@uranix

Comment: In general, elliptic functions are inverse to elliptic integrals (please see the integral in @Nassers answer, it needs to be solved for $x(t)$ - hence we need the inverse of it). They are non-elementary functions, so I'd like to ask - why do you need an analytical expression for the solutions?

Comment: My Professor give it as a task, that's why I asked, So I think we have an integral like $$t=\pm\int {dx\over \sqrt{{2\over3}\alpha x^3-\omega^2x^2+c_2}}$$ this, and this integral can't be find using analytic methods, right @uranix

Comment: @QFTaddict could it be that $\alpha$ is a small parameter and you are not expected to find an exact solution, but a series solution? Like in perturbation theory

Comment: Yeah I got it, but if we take the arbitrary constant $c_2=0$, then the integral is solvable, I got the solution... Please let me know what would you think about this@uranix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the ode as
\begin{align*}
              x^{\prime \prime}&=\left(\alpha  x-\omega^{2}\right) x
\end{align*}
Multiplying both sides by $x^{\prime}$ gives
\begin{align*}
              x^{\prime} x^{\prime \prime}&=\left(\alpha  x-\omega^{2}\right) x x^{\prime}
\end{align*}
Integrating both sides w.r.t. $t$ gives
\begin{align*}
\int{x^{\prime} x^{\prime \prime}\, \mathrm{d}t}  &=\int{\left(\alpha  x-\omega^{2}\right) x x^{\prime}\, \mathrm{d}t}\\ 
\int{x^{\prime} x^{\prime \prime}\, \mathrm{d}t}  &=\int{\left(\alpha  x-\omega^{2}\right) x\, \mathrm{d}x} \tag{1}                
\end{align*}
But
$$
\int{x^{\prime} x^{\prime \prime}\, \mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{2} \left(x^{\prime}\right)^2
$$
Hence equation (1)  becomes
\begin{align*}
            \frac{1}{2} \left(x^{\prime}\right)^2  &=\int{\left(\alpha  x-\omega^{2}\right) x\, \mathrm{d}x} \tag{2}                
\end{align*}
But
$$
              \int{\left(\alpha  x-\omega^{2}\right) x\, \mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{3} \alpha  \,x^{3}-\frac{1}{2} \omega^{2} x^{2}
$$
Therefore  equation (2)  becomes
\begin{align*}
               \frac{1}{2} \left(x^{\prime}\right)^2  &=\frac{1}{3} \alpha  \,x^{3}-\frac{1}{2} \omega^{2} x^{2} + c_2
\end{align*}
Where $c_2$ is an arbitrary constant of integration.

This is first order ODE which is now solved for $x$.

Solving for $x^{\prime}$ gives
\begin{align*}
x^{\prime}&=\frac{\sqrt{6 \alpha  x^{3}-9 \omega^{2} x^{2}+18 c_{2}}}{3}\tag{1} \\ 
x^{\prime}&=-\frac{\sqrt{6 \alpha  x^{3}-9 \omega^{2} x^{2}+18 c_{2}}}{3}\tag{2} 
\end{align*}

These are separable. So just need to do integrtion. But there does not
seem to be closed form solution to these elliptical type integrals. At least Maple could not do it. Integrating using Maple gives

$$
x_1(t) = \int_{0}^{x(t)}\frac{3}{\sqrt{6 \textit{_a}^{3} \alpha -9 \textit{_a}^{2} \omega^{2}+18 c_{2}}}d \textit{_a} -t -c_{1} = 0
$$

Similarly to the other ode.
$$
x_2(t) = \int_{0}^{x(t)}-\frac{3}{\sqrt{6 \textit{_a}^{3} \alpha -9 \textit{_a}^{2} \omega^{2}+18 c_{2}}}d \textit{_a} -t -c_{1} = 0
$$

Comment: From your Equation 1 and Equation 2, we can write $$t=\pm\int {dx\over \sqrt{{2\over3}\alpha x^3-\omega^2x^2+c_2}}$$, Please let me know, Without using a maple calculator can we solve or do something with this integral?@Nasser

Comment: @QFTaddict Substituting $x = A \wp + B$ into $(x')^2 = a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_0$, we can obtain the standard form $(\wp')^2 = 4 \wp^3 - g_2 \wp - g_3$. Thus a general solution is
$$x = \frac 6 \alpha \wp(t + C_1) + \frac {\omega^2} {2 \alpha}$$
with $(g_2, g_3) = (\omega^4/12, C_2)$.